# How to keep java.awt.List from covering javax.swing.JMenu

Tags: java, netbeans, drop-down-menu, awt, jmenu

To put this simply, I have some Menus in my Menu Bar that, when at start of the application, goes over a List when you expand it. However, if the List is ever updated, the Menus will go behind the List, covering Menu Items.

I have theorized that I need to when the list is updated, to make tell the list to go back to its layer (which I set it to the bottom, lowest on the list in application I am using which is NetBeans). But, I do not know what to call to tell the program to keep the list there. (I am still very new to Java and learning as I go) Does anybody have an idea on how to do what I wish or even better, what is causing the problem?

Thank you for your time and have a wonderful day :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JList instead of List.

The problem is that Components in java.awt have `peer` components, that are native OS components, whereas swing is 100% java. You cannot write over these native peers... at least not in java.

Comment: So I can't make it so it either updates the Menu or redraws it above the list?